# Regular express begin with "a" end with "b", and can not exist a or b between

Tags: regex

I use

```
a.*b
```

but when search `sssaxxxaxxxbss`,it gives me `axxxaxxxb`,not `axxxb`.

I need help! Thanks in advance！

Comment: Explicitly negating `a`, `b`: `a[^ab]*b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like

```
a[^ab]*b
```

- `[^ab]*` matches anything other than `a` or `b` zero or more times

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fS8zF8/3)

Comment: OP used * instead of +.

Comment: right,use * instead of + is what I want, thanks again!